# why infinite loop for my 8 queen issue?

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is my code, and wondering why it becomes infinite loop? Thanks.

```
class Solution(object):
    def Valid(self,result):
        currentX = len(result) - 1
        currentY = result[-1]
        if currentX == 0:
            return True
        for i in range(0, len(result) - 1):
            if result[i] == currentY:
                return False
            elif abs(i - currentX) == abs(result[i] - currentY):
                return False
        return True

    def NQueens(self, result):
        if result == []:
            row = 0
        else:
            row = len(result)
        for col in range(0, 8):
            result.append(col)
            if self.Valid(result) == True:
                print "check valid ok", row, col, result
                if row == 7:
                    print "result ok", result
                else:
                    self.NQueens(result)
            result.pop(-1)

        return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Solution()
    s.NQueens([])
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: use any IDE such as pycharm to debug the code

Comment: @Jack, I did debug but no ideas why it become infinite loop. If you have any insights, it will be great. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just finding all the solutions (your validation code is bugged, so they are a huge lot!).
You probably also want to exit your search whenever the first result is found...

```
            if row == 7:
                print "result ok", result
                exit();
```

To fix your Valid function:

```
for i in range(0, len(result)-1):
    if result[i] == Y or abs(i - X) == abs(result[i] - Y):
        return False
return True
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. Yes, you are correct that I want to find all solution, but I am using if/else and I never execute "self.NQueens(result)" when row is 7 (means a satisfied solution is found), not sure why infinite loop? Your insights are appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: You don't have any infinite loop! As I said,  your program finishes after some time, it is just printing a whole lot of junk (wrong 'solutions') because your Valid function is wrong. Start by making sure your validity check works...

Comment: what is wrong with Valid function?

Comment: just look at what it accepts! see my edit for correct validation

Comment: Hi Julien, I think the logics are the same. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: Then think again because you are wrong. Just try and you'll see mine works! Yours returns True as soon as one test succeeds instead of making sure ALL tests succeed. (Note the indentation difference...)

Comment: Hi Julien, I tried and it runs into infinite loop again? Are you sure it could run to complete?

Comment: Fix your indentation!

Comment: Hi Julien, which line? I am confused. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92682/discussion-between-julien-bernu-and-lin-ma).

Comment: Hi Julien, you are correct. I fixed the return True line indentation issue, and your if condition check and mine if-elif check seems the same? If I am wrong, please feel free to correct me. :)